# What is the Java equivalent for Enumerable.Select with lambdas in C#?

Tags: c#, java, java-8

Say I have an object in C#:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int Age{get;set;}
}
```

To select the names from this list in C# I would do the following:

```
List<string> names = person.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

How would I do the same thing in Java 8?

Comment: This LINQ line yields all names you have, not just one. Did you mean "To select just names from the list ..."?

Comment: See http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/ - Select ~ map.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: names* yes, basically wanted the most direct translation between the languages from the line "List<string> names = person.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();"

Comment: Yip, got it thanks. Wasn't sure if that was the best way to go about it at first. A simple C# lambda equates to using their stream implementation, mapping and messing with a Collectors object... Seems a bit silly.

Comment: @SamuelKDavis Using stream is not really any more silly/different than using IEnumerable (say LINQ2Objects, to keep the discussion focused) - that's effectively what a stream equates to. The collection at the end is equivalent of ToList (otherwise, who knows what sort of IEnumerable/stream the result is). It's different syntax (with less implicit conversions), but it's effectively an identical concept with similar complexity. And *thank goodness* Java will finally move out of the mid-20th century ..

Comment: Hmm actually you bring up very good points. I guess it isn't that bad after all. I still much prefer C#'s syntax.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you have a list of Persons like `List<Person> persons;` you can say

```
List<String> names
  =persons.stream().map(x->x.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or, alternatively

```
List<String> names
  =persons.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But collecting into a `List` or other `Collection` is intented to be used with legacy APIs only where you need such a `Collection`. Otherwise you would proceed using the stream’s operations as you can do everything you could do with a `Collection` and a lot more without the need for an intermediate storage of the `String`s, e.g.

```
persons.stream().map(Person::getName).forEach(System.out::println);
```